# Invoking video player application on Kindle Fire directly from WebView

Tags: android, kindle-fire

In my application I've got a WebView which might be used to display www.youtube.com or m.youtube.com content.  I've got the following code in the onLoadResource callback:

```
@Override
public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url)
{
    if(matchYouTubeWatchUrl(url))
    {
        invokeYouTubePlayer(m_context,url);
    }
}
```

The invokeYouTubePlayer function looks like this:

```
private static void invokeYouTubePlayer(Context c, String url)
{
    try
    {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        String videoId = uri.getQueryParameter("v");
        if(videoId != null)
        {
            Intent youtubeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            youtubeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("vnd.youtube://"+videoId));
            try
            {
                c.startActivity(youtubeIntent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"No handler for native youtube - expanding scope");
                // Try an alternate approach if there's no youtube app installed
                youtubeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                youtubeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+videoId));
                try
                {
                    c.startActivity(youtubeIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException e2)
                {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
 }
```

What I'm finding is that on most Android devices the first startActivity call invokes the YouTube application, however on KF what I'm seeing is that it invokes the browser which then invokes a video player application.

Not having a KF myself what I'd like to find out is whether there's a URI that can be passed to startActivity which will directly invoke the video player on Kindle Fire without having to pass through the browser as an intermediate step.

Answer (score 1):

Just a observation. There is a better way to detect if a Intent can be called

```
private boolean isCallable(Intent intent) {
        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Ok just to be clear on KF it never fires first activity then it fires second and then KF takes over and takes you to the YouTube app.

If so all i can think is that your details in first Intent is not correct or for KF its not the same as in other phones/tab

Comment: Great thanks for that code sample. Yes the issue with the KF is that the intent differs from other android devices which have a builtin youtube app.

Comment: what you can try is plug kindle in and look at logcat to see what gets called when you click youtube application...

Comment: Yeah that's what I'd do if I had one. Unfortunately I don't and the logcat I have access to doesn't have the information either.